# ag-grid in Angular 8: Auto-sizing columns doesn't work for client-siding pages

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) Community Edition 22.1.1 with Angular 8.2.14. My table uses client-side paging (all data is in the browser) with 25 rows per page.

My auto-sizing of columns is bound to `firstDataRendered`. It works on the current page but **not** for the other, non-visible pages. My auto-sizing method is also bound to the `paginationChanged` callback. So when I go to a different page, then the new page gets auto-sized. The columns are correctly sized this way, but "jump around" and look "jittery".

I used `suppressColumnVirtualisation=true`, as [recommended by ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#auto-size-columns). When I increase my paging size from 25 to 100, then column sizes are correct for the invisible rows on the **current** page, too. But it still does not work for other pages.

So can I auto-size columns in ag-grid across all pages? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to turn off row virtualization too.

In earlier versions, there was a 'suppressRowVirtualisation' property, 
but that's gone in later versions, and you have to specify the size of the 'rowBuffer' 
(how many off-screen rows are tracked by the grid), by specifying the 'rowBuffer' grid option (see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties)

If you want no row virtualization, you have to specify a rowBuffer size appropriately large, which I'll leave as an exercise for you :-)

Comment: Didn't work. Set `rowBuffer` to 250, still jumping around on pages 2-4 (records 26-100). I verified that my `gridOptions` are being used.